# Can you frame a casperjs web page?

Tags: web-scraping, cross-domain, casperjs

Casperjs navigates through webpages, and injects javascript on third party web pages on a headless mode.

Im wondering if it's possible to "show" the web page resulting of casperjs injecting some javascript on a web page of my own, via iframe or AJAX. In such a way that a user could interact with that web page.

Didn't add any code, since it's more of a theoretical question, can you jump around the "headless" mode of casperjs? would it be breaking the Cross Domain policy that Frame? Is it possible what Im asking?

I know it's not built to do this, but are there any workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: you want to show it on a website of your own or just save the print on your computer?

Comment: On a website of my own